# Does radiating heat cross path with another radiating heat nicely?

Tags: thermodynamics, infrared-radiation

Suppose two radiators, each on a wall perpendicular to the other. Do the two radiations impair each other?

Comment: Is this room in vacuum, or is it filled with air? This changes the dynamics of the problem considerably, as the primary means of heat transfer becomes radiation or convection, respectively.

Comment: full of air, down here on earth. I thought that a "radiator" is different from a "convector".

Comment: What is a convector, then? If a radiator is placed in an air-filled room, we have to examine the path length for the radiation produced. In totally dry air, the infrared radiation produced by a typical radiator propagates without hindrance, so then radiation is really the primary means of heat transfer. If the air has any amount of water in it, though, the infrared radiation is rapidly absorbed by the water, turning radiation into convection.

Comment: Thanks. So, with a humid environment, if i have a choice, i should choose a brutally radiating device, over a gentle one, for the radiating heat to reach across the room?

Comment: That depends on how insulated your walls are. If your walls are poorly insulated, allowing heat to drain from the room quickly, the temperature at the far walls will depend on the strength of the radiator; in this case, you'd be right, and you would need a more powerful radiator (though a dehumidifier might be a better investment at this point). However, if your walls are very well insulated, the temperature in the room will rise without bound, and you can choose whatever strength you like; the strength just determines the speed of the heating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an air-filled room, interference between individual photons from the radiators is irrelevant, as the radiation is rapidly absorbed by water in the air, and is homogenized by the Brownian motion of the air and water molecules. Therefore, the radiators do not significantly interfere with each other.

To intuitively see that this is true, we compare two radiators to two sound generators. Sound generators create pressure waves, which are alternating regions of positive and negative pressure. If a region of negative pressure from one sound generator overlaps with a region of positive pressure from another sound generator, the principle of superposition creates a region of static pressure (destructive interference).

Unlike sound generators, which can both pressurize and rarefy gas, radiators can only heat gas, and do not have the ability to cool down gas; radiation is either absorbed (in which case the gas gets hotter) or not (in which case the gas's temperature remains the same). Therefore, the cancellation that we see in the case of sound cannot happen here.